# Get updated data with update() from Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I want to get the newly updated data after updating Firestore.

```
eventRef.update({
                    snippet: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(object)
                }).then(res => {
                    console.log("Success");

                    // Proceed to update the Algolia object
                    return updateAlgoliaObject({
                        snippet: ???,
                        objectID: ID
                    });
```

How can I get the newly updated data so that I can use it and update the object in Algolia?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  It seems to me that you know that Cloud Functions can be involved here to accomplish your goal, but the final solution is going to require a lot of work.  Stack Overflow isn't a place to ask for someone to design and write your code like this.

Comment: so there's no easy way to get the object I guess

Comment: Have you read the documentation about writing Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions?  If not, you should start there.  Try writing a simple function first.  Then make it more complex when you understand how it works.

Comment: In just a client-side solution you can just attach a listener (either `get()` or `onSnapshot()` to the same `DocumentReference`, and get the latest `DocumentSnapshot` from there).